# How to get array of array value in Groovy which is passed from cURL url?

Tags: php, grails, groovy

I need to pass some user details from a PHP script to Grails. User details are wrapped into an array of array. In Groovy I can get the array element `def user = params.userName`. But how to get the element from the array of array or will it be useful if I get the whole array also?

From PHP I’m passing the array like this:

```
$userDetails = array ('currencyId' => 1,
              'contact' => array (
                        'city' => $city,
                        'countryCode' => $country,
                        'stateProvince' => $state,
                        'email' => $email),
        'userName' => $loginName,
        'password' => $pwd
);



$field_string = http_build_query($userDetails);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $field_string);
```

Comment: Give an example about how the actual data structure looks like.

Comment: @dmahapatro i included the array now.

Comment: Try to debug *params* and you'll find what data structure you deal with

Comment: encode as json and decode in grails with JSON.parse(params), then you should have access

Comment: im able to print results in both cases - i did debug params, passed array as json and parsed. But when i tried to get them to a variable in groovy controller im failed. I think im lacking the way how to access the value like as i said i can get the value by using "def user = params.userName" but when i tried similarly or altering i couldn't get the result

Comment: this is the result i got when i print json request         currencyId=1 
userName=test_login3
password=123
contact={"city":"Hyderabad","countryCode":"IN","stateProvince":"AP","email":"marikanti@gmail.com"}

Comment: but how to get the value of city in my action